# Getting an error when fetching data from the backend with ComponentDidMount - " TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator ....."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes, axios

I am trying to fetch data from the back end with ComponentDidMount but I am getting an error below:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'validateStatus' in 603e7632bf162c11422102f0
```

My Component did mount looks like this:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const authorization = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    const productId = this.props.match.params.id;

    axios
      .get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/product/${productId}`,
        this.state.productId,
        {
          headers: {
            authorization,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          productInfo: res.data,
        });
      });
  };
```

And the front end route end point:

```
http://localhost:3000/product/add/ph/m/p/details/603e7632bf162c11422102f0
```

I have another route that has very similar structure and I fetch the data with params in exactly same way and page is loading correctly with all data. To access the page where I am getting the error I do below:

```
<Link
     className="link"
        to={{ pathname: `/product/add/ph/m/p/details/${this.state.productId}` }} >
                <button>Continue</button>
 </Link>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need this in axios.get this.state.productId, and is it undefined or it has value?

Comment: Also, this looks like a BE error and not a FE so maybe put code from your node application where the get service is being triggered...

Comment: Hi, the value is there and the axios call does not go to BE at all ;/